# Role Limit (Internal + External) in a single Org

Tags: roles, role-hierarchy

How many Roles (Internal and External) can a single org have? I can't find this documented clearly without references to Territory count.

We know that Internal Roles and Account Roles are all stored in the UserRole table. Easy enough to query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, PortalType From UserRole
```

Internal Roles have a PortalType of 'None', Partner or Customer have their own respective PortalTypes. Simple.

What is the max we can store in this table?

[Documentation](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communities_share_crm_data/account_roles_hierarchy) for Account Role limits... 
- Default for new orgs: up to 5k
- Open a Case w/ SFDC: up to 100k
- SFDC Approval Required: up to 500k

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setup_roles_guidelines.htm&type=5) for Internal Roles...
- Default for new orgs: up to 500

[Additional Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329526&type=1&mode=1) for Internal Roles... *while this article is muddled up with legacy Territory Management, this is the only place I could find clear upper limits defined for Internal Roles:*
- By default, a Salesforce org can have up to 500 Roles or Territories. 
- The current Maximum is 10000. 
- A documented business case, including the specific amount of roles or territories needed, is required when requesting a higher limit.

At this point I infer - based on the above - that AT MOST a single org could have at most 510k roles... 500k (external) + 10k (internal). But this is a theoretical upper limit, as Salesforce Approval would be required.

Am I thinking about this right? Is this better documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Internal and external Roles will affect the org in the same way. Roles are Roles whether they're internal or external. Regardless of where they're used, the more you use, the slower things will get. I would not make the assumption that 510k is the max, but instead would conclude the max is **500k**.

Remember you need to provide a Business Use case justification for the total roles in your org to be extended to 500K. Why would Salesforce give you an extra 10k Roles without asking you justify that as well? Instead, if you needed that many roles, I'd expect you to running multiple instances of Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I agree with you - generally speaking - as an org approaches hundreds of thousands of Account Roles one would likely want to split orgs for the sake of performance. I agree with you that Salesforce may not even approve and grant that many Account Roles. But I come back to this... Salesforce Documentation CLEARLY draws a distinction between "Account Roles" (upper 500k) and "Internal Roles" (upper 10k) even if they are stored in the same table. Thus, I don't follow your "500k max" conclusion. Platform limits are often clearly defined... not so in this case.

Comment: Knowing how Salesforce works and how these decisions are made, I simply don't see the two being additive, particular since both will require justification (for different reasons of course). We may need to agree to disagree here.

Comment: I know this question is a bit older but I just stumbled upon this with the same question. For anyone else: Here's a more recent post about the same issue with more details https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325754/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-roles-for-community-plus-and-partner-users-50k-or and it's also referring to this helpful documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_partners_optimize_roles.htm&type=5. Short answer: "Total roles in an org for users with Customer Community Plus and Partner Community licenses. = 50,000"