# What is the maximum number of Roles for Community Plus and Partner users: 50k or 5k?

Tags: community, roles, role-hierarchy, portal

What is the maximum number of Roles for Community Plus and Partner users: 50 000 or 5 000?

I have read two different salesforce documentation articles which provide different information about the maximum number of roles.

[This article says that](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_force_com_system_overview_portal_roles.htm&type=5)

> The default number of roles used in an org’s portals or communities
> is 50,000. This limit includes roles associated with all of the
> organization’s customer portals, partner portals, or communities. To
> prevent unnecessary growth of this number, we recommend reviewing and
> reducing the number of roles. You can also delete unused roles.
> Contact customer support to increase your number of roles. If you
> require 100,000 roles or more, please contact your Salesforce account
> representative.

while [this articles says that](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_partners_optimize_roles.htm&type=5)

> Total roles in an org for users with Customer Community Plus and
> Partner Community licenses.   5,000   This allocation includes all roles
> associated with users in an org who hold Customer Community Plus and
> Partner Community licenses. If you need more roles, contact Salesforce
> Customer Support and ask for a Large User Volumes assessment

So basically one articles says that there can be up to 50000 roles and another articles says about 5000 roles. What is the exact limit or am I missing something? Do these articles discuss different roles?

Comment: The documentation is pretty confusing there, but I think it may be because the first article includes Portals as well as Communities which is a legacy technology. Going to have a dig to see if I can find a clear answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reached out to our Salesforce Product Development team internally and got a confirmation that the default org limit is 50K roles. Customers can increase it to 100K by filing a case with support.

Our team is working on updating the outdated [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_partners_optimize_roles.htm&type=5).

Also, per the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communities_share_crm_data/account_roles_hierarchy?trail_id=communities),

> New orgs can have a maximum of 50,000 roles by default. You need to contact support if you want to increase the number of roles to 100,000. The absolute maximum number of account roles you can have in Salesforce is 500,000, and you need Salesforce approval in order to have that many.

Regards,

Salesforce Support

Comment: This is one of the question on Community Cloud certification exam and the expected correct answer there is 5k, there is no 50k option amongst the answers. I have passed the Community Cloud certification exam yesterday and I think I had this question about the role count and there was no 50k option amongst the possible answers.

Comment: Could you please update the Community Cloud certification exam questions?

Comment: @Patlatus Thanks for pointing this. I will reach out to our team for inputs on this

Comment: I have got an update from our team that the exam question will be updated. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much!